# Tick-Tick noise / sound on Honda CB Unicorn 160

Tags: honda, unicorn

Last week I bought Honda CB Unicorn 160, I'm getting Tick-Tick sound after turned off the engine on silencer for even short ride, it's just 2 k.m. or a mile.

What will be the problem ? How do fix it ?

Comment: Sounds like it's cooling down - solution : let it cool down....

Comment: @SolarMike But, engine get hot that much with in a mile ?

Comment: "that hot" it will get hot - you are converting fuel to heat and heat to mechanical energy. this does not mean  that it is overheating necessarily.

Comment: @SolarMike You are saying it is normal , am i right.? Sorry I'm not good with english...

Answer (score 1):

The noise is any of the "hot" components cooling down and changing size or "settling" as they do so. So, cylinder head / fins, exhaust etc.

The engine will get hot after only 1 mile as it is small and working hard especially compared to a car engine with has a much larger thermal mass, which heats up more slowly in comparison.

Comment: Good point about the thermal mass of an automobile engine versus that of a 160cc motorbike.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 was gonna day that. By comparison, my 300 is fully warm in (give-or-take) 2 City blocks if I just take off!

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem. It's likely the exhaust system materials flexing & contracting as they're cooling down.